# Newsfeed in Rails, unidentified method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a simple newsfeed in rails. The aim is for it to return all the posts from the groups the user is following. I am using [`socialization`](https://github.com/cmer/socialization) for my follow functionality.

The exact error is:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `followees' for false:FalseClass)
```

Here are my basic models not including `like` and `follow` as they're empty:

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!
  attr_accessible :username, :password, :email
  has_many :groups
  has_many :posts
  acts_as_follower
  acts_as_liker

  before_create :generate_auth_token

  def auth_token_expired?
    auth_token_expires_at < Time.now
  end

  def generate_auth_token(expires = nil)
    self.auth_token = SecureRandom.hex(20)
    self.auth_token_expires_at = expires || 1.day.from_now
  end

  def regenerate_auth_token!(expires = nil)
    Rails.logger.info "Regenerating user auth_token"
    Rails.logger.info "  Expiration: #{expires}" if expires
    generate_auth_token(expires)
    save!
  end
end
```

Group:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :user_id
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_followable 
end
```

Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :user_id, :group_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  acts_as_likeable
end
```

I have setup a function named `newsfeed` in my `post` controller. The function grabs all the groups that a user is following and then grabs all the posts that have `group_id`s matching `group_id`s in the returned groups array. But I keep getting `unidentified method followees`(socialization provides this). Yet it appears to work when using single users and posts in `irb`.

```
 def newsfeed 
    @groups = current_user.followees(Group)
    @posts = Post.where(:group_id => @groups)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
 end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What class name is written for the `unidentified method` error?

Comment: Make sure that your users are logged in using a `before_filter`. It is possible that you are not currently logged in.

Comment: @UriAgassi The posts class has a before_filter :require_auth so it wouldn't get to the code without someone being logged in. Uri the exact error I'm getting in the console is **NoMethodError (undefined method `followees' for false:FalseClass)** I've added it to the question now sorry.

Comment: @JustinWood Explained what happened in my reply to the main answer. You were correct though justin so thanks a lot, I've up voted your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, your `current_user` method returns `false`, instead of a user. Check what's returned from that method, as find out why you get the error...

Comment: Just retried it and it worked perfectly. I realised I have an expiry time on my auth_token which is pretty short so my auth_token must of ran out before sending the first request. Which would of logged the user out. Thanks for your prompt help Uri.

Answer (score 1):

Your current_user return false instead of instance of User. You may see it from error text.